# Problems with Dokka for private functions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

With Dokka 1.8.10 i got Problemsto show the private functions of my classes. I tried includeNonPublic.set(true) with an older version (which worked) but for 1.8.10 this mehtod is deprecated...

I'm searchin for an solution, that shows my private functions in the classes.

So this is my code in the build.gradle (:app)

I think this are the relevant parts.

```
import org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask



plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.dokka' version '1.8.10'
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    dokkaPlugin 'org.jetbrains.dokka:android-documentation-plugin:1.8.10'
}
```

...

```
// Configure all single-project Dokka tasks at the same time,
// such as dokkaHtml, dokkaJavadoc and dokkaGfm.
tasks.withType(DokkaTask.class) {

    moduleName.set(project.name)
    moduleVersion.set(project.version.toString())
    outputDirectory.set(file("build/dokka/$name"))
    failOnWarning.set(false)
    suppressObviousFunctions.set(true)
    suppressInheritedMembers.set(true)
    offlineMode.set(false)

    dokkaSourceSets.configureEach {
        /*documentedVisibilities.set([
                DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PUBLIC,
                DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PROTECTED
        ])*/

        perPackageOption {
            matchingRegex.set(".*internal.*")
            suppress.set(true)
            //documentedVisibilities.set([Visibility.PRIVATE])
        }
    }
}

dokkaHtml {
    outputDirectory.set(file("build/documentation/html"))
}


tasks.dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            // A set of visibility modifiers that should be documented
            // If set by user, overrides includeNonPublic. Default is PUBLIC
            documentedVisibilities.set(listOf(DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PRIVATE) + documentedVisibilities.get())


            //includeNonPublic.set(true)
            skipDeprecated.set(true)
            reportUndocumented.set(true)
            noAndroidSdkLink.set(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle with Kotlin DSL, use:

```kotlin
documentedVisibilities.set(listOf(DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PRIVATE)
                           + documentedVisibilities.get())
```

(it seems the `add` method does not work properly)

Gradle with Groovy syntax:

```
documentedVisibilities.set([DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PRIVATE])
```

Maven:

```xml
<puglin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
    <artifactId>dokka-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.15</version>
    <configuration>
       <includeNonPublic>true</includeNonPublic>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hey Dimitry,
thanks for your answer. It still don't work... :(

I get the issue, that there is a problem with the property 'unsuppressedSourceSets'. In the next answer i try to show my code.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you got?

Comment: I already fixed the issue. Instead of listOf() i put my Visibilities in [ ] and it worked.

Comment: I just saw you're using the groovy syntax and not the kotlin DSL. I changed my answer to cover all cases. Feel free to update it with something is missing

Comment: Nono, it's working fine now. Thank you for that!

Now i got another problem. My classes get printed 5 times in the HTML-Output. But i think it is a problem with the flavors or buliding variants of our app.